# How to gradually increase teleport amount

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an armor stand accelerate towards the ground, but the method I am using to move it is teleporting it forward, so it won't go down in the process. I can't find any way to use a scoreboard to increase the amount so I'm wondering if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a scoreboard which constantly is added to the armor stand. As the score gets higher, you can use more and more command blocks.

Run once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add speed dummy
```

Run on a clock:

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] speed 1
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,scores={speed=1..}] at @s run tp @s ~ ~-0.1 ~
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,scores={speed=50..}] at @s run tp @s ~ ~-1 ~
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,scores={speed=100..}] at @s run tp @s ~ ~-2 ~
```